# Incomplete Ubuntu 12.04 install dual-boot XP

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot

This weekend has been the 1st time I've tried to install Ubuntu.

On the initial install, (I am using a USB) the installation went all the way through and asked to restart when completed. *I was not able to get grub to boot* and kept going through Windows.

After some research I found some articles on updating/reinstalling grub, so I followed those. I finally *got grub to load* after a day but there was *no Windows option* only the Ubuntu 12.04 which when I selected it only gave me a `fatal error 17`.

I booted from the USB again and *deleted the partitions and installed again*. This time I got an `error 15`.

I then booted through XP and *downloaded the WUBI.exe* and uninstalled Ubuntu and reinstalled again. The installation went to the very end and then gave an error message (which I don't remember exactly what it said) something along the lines of checking my logs on my C drive.

I then uninstalled Ubuntu and removed the wubi.exe file and *wiped my USB* and did the download to the USB again. Booted through USB and *ran the install process again*. It again went through the install process but after creating username and password and hitting continue, the installation dialogue box disappears and the mouse spinning wheel is displayed, but **I do not receive the prompt to restart**. I can still access the side menu for Ubuntu but the wheel keeps spinning.

How do I get Ubuntu to install properly?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost the Ubuntu download must be **checksummed**. It can be done automatically if you use **Free Download Manager** if you download from Windows. If you want to dualboot with Windows download the **Wubi** type Ubuntu installer otherwise the original will do. Also the Ubuntu you download, Please download the one which is compatible with your motherboard, I mean 32-bit if your motherboard supports 32 bit OS or 64-bit if your motherboard supports 64-bit OS. Rest of the software including Flashplayer and others you can get it from Ubuntu Software Centre or Synaptic, whichever one you prefer.
Or you can buy it from the Linux market to get a properly checksummed Ubuntu Operating System. It is very cheap.
Good luck.